# AspectJ - exclude inner classes from within clause

Tags: java, aspectj

I have a marker interface which has several implementations. My intention is to add an aspect for all public methods defined in any class implementing that marker interface.
I defined my aspect as follows:

```
@Around("within(x.y.z.MyInterface+) && execution(public * *(..))")
```

The problem is that this also catches inner classes, for example consider this method in one of the classes implementing that interface:

```
public void foo() {
  doSomething(new Request() {
    @Override
    public void do() {
      System.out.println("Hi");
    }
  });
}
```

For some reason, the aspect also catches that "do()" method, even though it is does not inherit from MyInterface.

How should I fix my aspect definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `"within"` use the `"this"` pointcut:

```
@Around("this(x.y.z.MyInterface+) && execution(public * *(..))")
```

Basically `"this"` matches joinpoints where *this*, the current object reference at the time, is an instance of MyInterface. Anonymous classes not implementing your interface will no longer match.

JavaWorld has a nice article on it:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074048/core-java/i-want-my-aop---part-2.html?page=2

Comment: Thanks! I saw that if using Spring AOP I can also use "target", just noticed that later.